# Code working only in one compiler

Tags: c

I was doing homework and when i thought i finally did it fail to work in Visual Studio.
 I have code like this and its working perfectly fine in Dev C++, but its not in Visual Studio. Can you explain me why and how to fix it.

Edit: Its compiling in both. In VS its display always 0, and it should 0 for text and a integers and for integers this number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>

#define czy_cyfra( c )    (( c ) > '0' && ( c ) < '9' )
#define jaka_cyfra( c )   (( c ) - '0' )

int czy_liczba_calkowita(char * a)
{

    if (*a == '\0')
        return -1;
    do
    {
        if (!czy_cyfra(*a))
            return -1;
    } while (*++a != '\0');
    return 0;
}

int jaka_liczba(char * a)
{
    int liczba = 0;
    do
    {
        liczba = liczba * 10 + jaka_cyfra(*a++);
    } while (*a != '\0');
    return liczba;
}

int main()
{
    char a[255];
    printf("Wprowadz lancuch\n");
    scanf_s("%s", a);
    printf("%u", czy_liczba_calkowita(a) == 0 ? jaka_liczba(a) : 0);
    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What is it doing or not doing that it shouldn't be doing or should be doing?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow! When posting code that is problematic in some way, you need to explain EXACTLY what is going wrong. What are your expectations? What is the exact text of the error? Is it a runtime error or a compile time error? Also if the question is about C++, then don't tag it as C. If you are compiling it as C++ then it is a C++ question. Finally, you generally need to produce a minimal, complete, verifiable example, or your question is off-topic. Please see the help center for more info!

Comment: What is the `scanf_s()` doing without a size argument?

Comment: It compiled in one but not in another? Re @EOF comment - apart from *undefined behaviour* compilers do not all check the arguments to such functions.

Comment: Code placed after a return is not very useful (last line).

Comment: It's ironic: MSVC uses these "safer" functions yet the compiler does not even check you passed the extra arguments required! `scanf_s("%s", a, (unsigned)sizeof a);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed out an argument for `scanf_s` and this results in *undefined behaviour* - which may or may not work. It should be

```
scanf_s("%s", a, (unsigned)sizeof a);
```

The reason for the `unsigned` cast? The [MSVC man page for `scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) says

> The size parameter is of type unsigned, not size_t.

Not all compilers check that you have supplied arguments for all the fields of `XscanXX` and `XprintXX` families. For example, MSVC 9.0 does not check these supposedly "safer" functions for the correct number of arguments, but MSVC 14.0 does, giving a compilation error.